# Why is Unity 2D running so much faster on system with ATI 6770?

Tags: 11.10, unity, ati, 2d

I'm new to Linux in general.  I installed 11.10 the other day, and began enjoying.  I've noticed, however, that when I choose "Ubuntu" from the login menu (vs "Ubuntu 2D), the system runs noticeably slower.  Nothing major, but window movements are jerky, programs take longer to open, and log-in is substantially slower.  When I load "Ubuntu 2D", everything is snappy.

My system is an Athlon II x4 @ 3.0 Ghz and an AMD 6770.

Ubuntu tells me that the proprietary drivers are non-active, but I did install catalyst earlier.

Something tells me this has to do with drivers.  What's my next step?

Comment: It seems that your current configuration is not rendering 3D acceleration fast enough. Did you try Gnome Classic per chance? You can try Gnome Classic in both 3D and 2D, see if you notice a difference there. If 3D is still slow, you may want to consider re-installing your driver. Did you install the Catalyst driver from a downloaded binary or from Synaptic? The one in Synaptic is essentially the one you see in the Drivers Manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Graphics drivers through the software center or the 'Additional driver' button in system settings I would suggest to reinstall them using the newest driver package from the amd website.
It's a pretty straight forward process and done very quickly through the terminal, just copy and paste every command I put here.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*

sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

These commands remove the previously installed drivers and make sure all the dependencies for the new drivers are included.
These next ones download and activate the driver installer script from amd

```
cd $HOME/Downloads

wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run

sudo chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run

sudo sh amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

The graphical amd installer will now guide you through the driver installation (just as it would in windows for example)
After it's done just type

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Now reboot your system and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

AMD graphics drivers are very poor on Linux. Happens to me on an AMD 6850 as well. Very jerky window movement.